# RESULT_CODE_INVALID_CMDLINE_URL when running a react app

Tags: reactjs, browser

I had a react app that was working fine before my computer was force shut. I am using `npm start` to serve my app in a local server. When I reopen my computer and start my server the first page( the `"/" url`) works fine, but when I push a new url to the history( `props.history.push("/pages")`), the browser freezes and it give me this error [image].  This was in chromium and I even tried it with other browsers like firefox but the browser just freezes. Assuming the problem might be with my computer I have also tried other devices on the network and the same problem keeps happening. I have even cleared the npm cache by `npm cache clean --force`. But nothing solves the problem and it is frustruting to debug since nothing is printed on the dev tools and no error message is throwen by react. If some one has come accross such a problem would like to hear a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This had happened to me a couple of times. This seems to keep happening in chrome browser when you have an array and you are pushing too many items to it (it is like

### **stackoverflow:)**

). You may want to edit your question so that more people can benefit from these, it isn't actually a react problem. It is a limitation in browsers I guess. They should at least warn you about what the error is. so for anyone who wants to regenerate this problem use the following code in the chromium console or run any js script on your chromium browser.

```
    let arr = [];
    let arrcounter = 13;
    for (let x = 1; x <= arrcounter; x) {
        arr.push(x);
    }
```

This is an infinite loop as `x` isn't being incremented, which means an infinite amount of 1's are pushed to the array which causes the above error. This atleast was in my case. There might be other reasons for this problem to be caused, but check for such a mistakes in your code because neither your browser (which is a bammer) nor your editor notify you about such mistake. If this solves your mistake let me know.

As to how to debug your code.

You can start by commenting out all your code except the necessary react requirements then uncommenting each part in a controlled way to see which part of your code is causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, it turns out I mistakenly removed ++. I didnt even know when I have done that. That is a life saver. But browsers should have something like a segmentaion fault message like a c would give you.